# What Was the Educational Series About an Alien Learning Library Skills?

Tags: story-identification, tv

In 1986 or so I watched an educational series about an alien that came to a post-apocalyptic earth. He was stuck and had to learn to use the library in order to get the information that he needed to survive. Does anyone remember the name of the series?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did you watch this on TV? And was it animated or live-action?

Comment: Thank you Dosco Jones. Your ability to recall this is certainly uncanny. My daughter and I are eating watermelon and she ask me about the nutritional content and that sparked my memory. I remember wanting to see this show beginning to end and now I have the chance. Thanks again!

Comment: @LogicDictates, I watched episode 6 "Information Quick" of "Tomes & Talismans" on Library day in elementary school some time in 1986.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe [Tomes & Talismans](https://ddc.typepad.com/025431/2020/10/tomes-talismans-teaching-dewey-with-a-post-apocalyptic-sci-fi-twist.html), 1986?

> In 1986, Mississippi Public Broadcasting created a show so wild that
> many of us who watched it as kids thought we had imagined it in a
> fever dream. Tomes & Talismans was a 13-part television series that
> was designed to educate schoolchildren about how to find library
> resources, but with a dark, complex plotline: at the end of the 21st
> century, an alien race called "the Wipers" colonizes a polluted and
> overcrowded Earth, destroying data technology. But that's just the
> prelude! One hundred years after that, a librarian named Ms. Bookhart
> is the only human left on the planet, and must teach another alien
> race called "the Users" to use the resources of the last library on
> Earth to find a way to defeat the Wipers.
>
> I was never one of those kids who always knew they wanted to be a
> librarian, but this series really made an impact on me after watching
> it in my elementary school's library in the fifth grade. I'm sure it
> helped guide me to a love of science fiction (I only wish I had had
> access to Doctor Who back then!). Library workers and Dewey fans will
> find a lot to love in Tomes & Talismans, especially in episode five,
> which is all about the DDC.

Episode 1: